# How can I map an array of ids to other table in Hibernate?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I found that I can do `@JoinColumn` to join two tables. For example I have `profile_photo_id` in `usr` table that maps to `photo` table. The `Usr` object I get would have a `photo` object instead of int.

The problem I have now is I have a column `photoIds` which is an array of integer with ids associated with `photo` table. How can I correctly map my array of int to array of `photo` object? I'm using postgresql.

**EDITED**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class Usr {
    @Id
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String name;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "updated_at", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date updatedAt;

    @Getter
    @Column(name = "created_at", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date createdAt;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "photo_ids")
    private Integer[] photoIds; // ideally is to convert this to array of photo object
}
```

Then photo entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "photo")

public class Photo {
    @Id
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    private String url;
}
```

my usr table

```
root::DATABASE=> \d+ usr
                                                                            Table "public.usr"
       Column        |              Type              |                     Modifiers                     | Storage  | Stats target |               Description
---------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------------------------------
 id                  | integer                        | not null default nextval('usr_seq'::regclass)     | plain    |              |
 name                | character varying(255)         |                                                   | extended |              |
 updated_at          | timestamp(0) without time zone | default now()                                     | plain    |              |
 created_at          | timestamp(0) without time zone | not null default now()                            | plain    |              |
 photo_ids           | integer[]                      |                                                   | extended |              |
```

Comment: I'm not sure that Hibernate can map an array.  Could you instead use an `ArrayList` to store your IDs?

Comment: I don't find postgresql having `ArrayList`. how can you store `ArrayList` object in db?

Comment: I think you are having some confusion about all this.  If the entity class for your `profile_photo_id` table has an `ArrayList` of photos, this simply denotes a one-to-many (or maybe many-to-many) relationship between the two tables.  Each element in that list corresponds to a record in the other table.

Comment: yes, the goal is to have a collection of `photo` object, but `usr` table stores an array of `photo_ids`

Comment: I could've done something like 
    `@JoinColumn(name = "profile_photo_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Photo profilePhoto;` for one to one relationship

Comment: but I have no idea how to correctly map all the `photo` objects?

Comment: You should include your code for the user entity class.  Then maybe someone can suggest how to handle the array of IDs.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to construct the entity class that's why I didn't post my code, but I have posted some code to express my question clearly. Thank you!

Comment: So I am saying you probably want to use `private List<Integer> photoIds` instead of an array.

Comment: I'm afraid that might not be something I can control. I've added my `usr` table.

Comment: hibernate would map the `photo_ids` directly from db to my entity. but even if I can do `List`, what I want is a list of `Photo` object not id.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mispoke.  You want to use `List<Photo>` in your user entity class.

Comment: yes, that's fantastic. I don't really care if its an array or a collection. how can I accomplish?

Comment: Honestly, you might want to start with a good tutorial, [such as this one](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/).  Posting broad questions on Stack Overflow is probably a poor way to learn Hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

Try modifying your pojo to following

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class Usr {
@Id
@Setter
@Getter
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

@Getter
@Column(name = "updated_at", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Date updatedAt;

@Getter
@Column(name = "created_at", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Date createdAt;

@Getter
@Setter
@OneToMany(name = "photo_ids")
private List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
}
```

This will give an Array of 'Photo'object. Also the best practice is to set 'hibernate.hbm2ddl' to auto this will save you from hard work of matching your POJO's to database tables.

Comment: no, it doesn't work. I know one to many would work if my photo_ids is a single int, but it is integer[]